# Binary Search Tree insert not creating data on the heap even though the "new" keyword is used

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, heap-memory

Im having an issue with my code as its not inserting a node on the heap. I GDBed the code to see what was happening and i found out that its inserting the data correctly and making a node but after the function ends the node is destroyed and its reset to NULL. So I'm thinking that its not correctly being created on the heap but i use the "new" keyword so I'm pretty stumped. Anyways heres my code any help would be much appreciated.

```
int BST::insert(int data)
{
int isSuccess;
if(head == NULL)
{
    head = new BSTNode(data);
    return data;
}   
else
{   
    if(data < head->data)
        isSuccess = insertTreeNode(head->left,data);
    else if(data > head->data)
        isSuccess = insertTreeNode(head->right,data);
    else
        return 0;
}

return isSuccess;
}
```

Here is a aux function

```
int BST::insertTreeNode(BSTNode* temp,int data)
{
int returnVal = data;
if(temp == NULL)
    temp = new BSTNode(data);
else if(data < temp->data)
    returnVal = insertTreeNode(temp->left,data);
else if(data > temp->data)
    returnVal = insertTreeNode(temp->right,data);
else
    returnVal = 0;
return returnVal;
}
```

Here is h file for BSTNode

```
#ifndef BSTNODE_H
#define BSTNODE_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BSTNode
{
public:
    BSTNode* left;
    BSTNode* right;
    int data;
    BSTNode(int);
private:

};
#endif
```

Sorry about the formatting. Also head is a type BSTNode*

Comment: And `head` isd actually defined where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that you are changing the pointer inside your function but it is not seen outside your function.

Change your function signature to this:

```
int BST::insertTreeNode(BSTNode * & temp,int data)
```

I won't comment on any other portion of your code.

Comment: Thank you and I know there are some bad programming practices in my code mainly with everything being public and some other things but security isn't an issue, its just something I'm doing to learn more about BST's.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't commenting on how good or bad your code was.  Just the fact that I hadn't looked at it other than to solve your specific issue.  Please accept the answer.

Comment: IOW C++ parameters are passed by value - even when they're pointers. You can change the pointed-to value, but the parameter itself (within the function) is effectively a local variable containing a copy of the original pointer, so changes to the pointer are lost when the function exits. The same applies to a reference except that you *can't* change a reference after initialization (in this case, when it's passed) - because of the self-dereferencing behaviour you can only change what the reference references, not the reference itself.

Comment: I thought that was what was happening at first but i figured since it was a pointer it was going to be treated like a pass by reference. I was wrong though, thanks for the explanation!!!!